# Grails 3.x - Customizing scaffolding-generated views

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I'm a Grails 2.x developer and I'm trying to jump to Grails 3.x and Java 8. But I feel disappointed with the scaffolding process results. It generates these views (GSP files): `create.gsp`, `edit.gsp`, `show.gsp` and `index.gsp`.

So, some things have changed:

- The `form.gsp` file is missing. I think it's been replaced (to
  generate the form) in the `create.gsp` and `edit.gsp` files with this code: `<f:all bean="myDomainClass"/>`.
  IMHO this is really sad. Customizing our forms is the most natural
  thing.
- The same has happened with the `show.gsp` and `index.gsp` files,   replacing the customizable generated code with `<f:display bean="myDomainClass" />` and `<f:table collection="${myDomainClassList}" />` respectively.

So, how can I customize the form or generate a `form.gsp` like file? How can I customize the `show.gsp` and `index.gsp` files? Is there a way to generate views as Grails 2.x does? Can we avoid the usage of `<f:all />`, `<f:display />` and `<f:table/>` tags?